# Block if without end if - VBA Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, if-statement

This is a small snippet of the code I am writing. It seems to throw an "BLOCK IF WITHOUT END IF" error on the last line. I can't spot an error here, after consulted with this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) link

```
    If Longs > 10 & Shorts > 10 Then
                 If Longs < Shorts Then
                       Pairs = Longs
                 Else
                       Pairs = Shorts
                 End If
    Else
      If Longs < 10 & Shorts > 10 Then
                      Shortfall = True
                      Pairs = 10
     Else: Shortfall = False
                      Pairs = 10 
End If              
End Sub
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: it's most likely because of that inline `Else:` that's missing an `End If`, should it be `Else: Shortfall = false: Pairs = 10: End If`?

Comment: I always use a free add-in called "Smart Indent" to get a nice indentation of code when I inherit some visually horrible code like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 3 `If` but only 2 `End If`, change the `End Sub` at the end to `End If`.

If you indent the code properly, it'll be much easier to see:

```
If Longs > 10 & Shorts > 10 Then
   If Longs < Shorts Then
      Pairs = Longs
   Else
      Pairs = Shorts
   End If
Else
   If Longs < 10 & Shorts > 10 Then
      Shortfall = True
      Pairs = 10
   Else 
      Shortfall = False
      Pairs = 10 
   End If              
' missing End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was working in terms of C type method if [if statements] else if [statements] ... else [do the rest] So was giving higher priority to the last while its actually a nested Else.

Answer (score 2):

Change your

```
Else
    If Longs < 10 & Shorts > 10 Then
```

to

```
ElseIf Longs < 10 & Shorts > 10 Then
```

That way you're not unnecessarily nesting `If` constructs, but just adding an extra condition to your outer `If` construct.

Like this:

```
If Longs > 10 & Shorts > 10 Then
    If Longs < Shorts Then
        Pairs = Longs
    Else
        Pairs = Shorts
    End If
ElseIf Longs < 10 & Shorts > 10 Then
    Shortfall = True
    Pairs = 10
Else 
    Shortfall = False
    Pairs = 10 
End If
```

Heck, you can even leave this intact, even though it's quite ugly:

```
Else: Shortfall = False
                Pairs = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
   `Else: Shortfall = False`
into

```
Else 
   Shortfall = False
   Pairs = 10
end if
```